# Cypress: Is it possible to complete a test after failure

Tags: url, cypress, http-status-codes, end-to-end

## Overview

I want to automatically test all 200 pages of our website every week after the update to see if the update broke any of them

## The test case

- Login and go to the sitemap
- Get the URLs and check each for their HTTP status

## The code

```
    it('check HTTP status', () => { 
        cy.visit(Cypress.config('siteMapUrl'))
        
        cy.get('.portlet-separator').should('contain', 'Available Links')
        
        cy.get('.inputwrapper>a')
            .each(($el, index, $list) => {
                if($list){
                    cy.get($el)
                        .invoke('attr', 'href')
                        .then(href => {
                            cy.request(Cypress.config('url')+href)
                            .should('have.property', 'status', 200)
                        })
                }
        })
```

## What happens:

Once an URL returns anything else than status 200 the test fails.

## What I would like:

I would like Cypress to iterate through the complete list of URLs before returning the URLs that failed.

## Why?

If more than one URL in the list is broken, I will not find the 2nd broken URL with this test until our devs have fixed the first one. Yet I need to produce a list with all broken URLs at the beginning of the week

I have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67548643/extract-sitemap-urls-and-cy-request-each-url-per-a-unique-test-cypress) but I would like to know if there is a different solution before I try to implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `.should()` after each URL - that will fail immediately, even if setting `failOnStatus: false`.

Instead save the results and check at the end.

```js
const failed = []

cy.get(".inputwrapper>a").each(($el, index, $list) => { 
  cy.get($el)
    .invoke("attr", "href")
    .then((href) => {
      cy.request({
        url: Cypress.config("url") + href,
        failOnStatusCode: false,      
      })
      .its('status')
      .then(status => {
        if (status !== 200) {
          failed.push(href)
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
.then(() => {
  // check inside then to ensure loop has finished
  cy.log(`Failed links: `${failed.join(', ')`)
  expect(failed.length).to.eq(0)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Seke. This is a truly impressive solution.

I was not aware that you can save the results in a callback function and only check them at the end.

This code works flawlessly. It runs everything in one test and logs all failed links. Just perfect.