# Cypress : how can I fail a test if an error occurs but only at the end of test run

Tags: javascript, cypress, sitemap

**UseCase :**

I want to automatically test all sitemap URLs (more than 1000) of our website after each new code release to see if we broke any of them.

**My problem :**

Test is done with no error even when a URL returns anything else than 200 but instead I need to save the results into sort of a callback function, check them and fail the test only at the end ( for both of my cy.request() ) if an error occurs in order to find all the broken links whithout stopping the test in the middle of test run.

**This is my code**

```
describe('Validate sitemaps files', () => {
let urls = []
let results = []
const failed = []

before(function () {
    cy.fixture('sitemaps.json').then((data) => {
        for (var index in data) {
            cy.log(data[index].url)
            cy.request({
                url: Cypress.config().baseUrl + data[index].url,
                failOnStatusCode: false,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36",
                },
            }).as("parentSitemapPath").then((responseParent) => {
                urls = Cypress.$(responseParent.body)
                    .find("loc")
                    .toArray()
                    .map((el) => el.innerText)
                cy.log(JSON.stringify(responseParent.status))
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    ????

                 }
            })
        }  
    })
})

it("Should succesfully load each url in the sitemap", () => {
    urls.forEach((url) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'HEAD',
            url: url,
            failOnStatusCode: false,
        }).as("childSitemapPath").then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                    ????

            }
        })
    })
})
```

})

I have already seen these answers ==> [Cypress: Is it possible to complete a test after failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256076/cypress-is-it-possible-to-complete-a-test-after-failure), [Denial of Service (status code 429) when testing sitemap links in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73751968/denial-of-service-status-code-429-when-testing-sitemap-links-in-cypress) but no success so far.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cy.wrap` and `.each` functions to pass the array of URLs into the Cypress command chain and iterate through them, similar to JavaScript's `.forEach()`. After we've finished sending requests to each URL, we can simply assert that the `failed` array has a length of 0.

```js
it("Should succesfully load each url in the sitemap", () => {
    cy.wrap(urls).each((url) => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'HEAD',
            url: url,
            failOnStatusCode: false,
        }).as("childSitemapPath").then(response => {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                // Add the url to the failed array - you can add other information if you'd prefer
                failed.push(url)
            }
        })
    }).then(() => {
        // Use a chai assertion to check the array is empty
        expect(failed).to.be.empty
        // Optionally, use cy.wrap to use a Cypress assertion
        cy.wrap(failed).should('have.length', 0)
    })
})
```

If you need to do this in your `before` hook as well, you can use the same logic of pushing the url/information to the `failed` array, and simply add a `.then()` after the `.then()` in which you are making the requests.